# Surrogate key part of business object?

Tags: php, orm, surrogate-key

I have a database table (mysql) representing the entity *Employee* in an enterprise like application. Surrogate keys are used throughout the database, so every *Employee* record has an auto incremented ID column identifying the Employee. I have modelled the Employee as a Business Object (BO) in php like this:

```
class Employee 
{
    public $id;    // surrogate key of database record
    public $firstName;
    public $user;
    public $posInCompany // associated EmployeePosition

    public function __construct($emplData)
    {
        $this->id = $emplData['id'];
        // ... init other properties
    }       
}
```

I am wondering if the `$id` property should be part of that class? Actually it represents the surrogate key from database and is thus storage-related. But I want the BOs to know nothing about the way they are stored/loaded (seperation of logic from persistence). The BOs hold the business logic for me and I want to work with them WITHOUT any coupling to type of storage (database etc.). With my above class layout I could never instantiate an *Employee* without giving an `$id`, so I guess this is not the correct way to implement a BO.

I want to work with DAO pattern to store/load *Employee*. Should I use the `$id` only within DAO concerns?

Further I am concerned about identifying an *Employee* object in my application later, which would work well with the surrogate `$id`. The `$user` property is also unique for every Employee in the database. So maybe I should use this property instead?

Comment: I dont know If I understand you correctly.. but if the ID only used in your class and other classes shouldnt get access to this id , use private $id instead of public $id...

Comment: No, my question is about the $id being part of the business object at all, considering decoupling from storage but also giving a way to identify an Employee in the application. - I have edited for mor clearance I hope.

Comment: If you dont need the surrogate id anywhere then dont make it a part of the object. Looks like you can get uniqueness from the $user variable so no need to have the $id in the object

Comment: No matter how objects are stored there is always going to be a need to be able to uniquely identify them.  That'd indicate you should keep the ID in the BO.  (On a side-note, public properties are really dangerous. I could put literally anything in them. You're better off making them non-public and implementing getters/setters that can protect against someone setting the object's props to an invalid state)

Comment: But I also have the possibility to identify them by property `$user` in application. So maybe I should use the `$id` in DAO part and `$user` in application part? Hmm, but what about BOs that do NOT have a further unique property? They can only be identified by surrogate key, won't they? Yes getters/setters are better for encapsulation.